# card.io does not scan

Tags: ios, iphone, card.io

trying to integrate Card.io (v. 5.1.1) into my application and facing very strange issue with iPhone4 iOS v. 7.1.2. When it starts camera:

1. it does not make autofocus of camera
2. if I cover the camera with something, it does not switch on the flash
3. when I put the card in green-angle frame it does nothing. no vertical/horizontal lines appearing. only some screen lagging from time to time

the strange thing is when I install card-io-sampleApp it works perfectly on same device with same cards. uber cardio works perfectly also. getting card-io-sampleApp controller into my application did not make any difference.

```
    (IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    CardIOPaymentViewController *scanViewController = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPaymentDelegate:self];
    scanViewController.disableManualEntryButtons = YES;
    scanViewController.suppressScanConfirmation = YES;
    scanViewController.scannedImageDuration = 0.5f;
    scanViewController.collectExpiry = NO;
    scanViewController.scanExpiry = NO;

    [self presentViewController:scanViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

(void)userDidCancelPaymentViewController:(CardIOPaymentViewController *)scanViewController
{
    [scanViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

 (void)userDidProvideCreditCardInfo:(CardIOCreditCardInfo )info inPaymentViewController:(CardIOPaymentViewController )scanViewController
{
    if (info.cardNumber.length > 0) {
        self.numberField.text = info.cardNumber;
    }
    [scanViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

what am I missing?
the application also uses camera for QR code scanning. could it be the issue? maybe some other conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what could cause this behaviour on iOS 7

If you have infinite animation somewhere you instantiate CardIOPaymentViewController it will not work properly.

Code snippet that cause problem

```
- (void)animate:(UIView *)v
{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
           // some animation
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
               [self animate:v];
        }];
}
```

So, stop animation when you present scanner, or when controller disappears.

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    // stop animation here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue,but how implement this solution,i have not use any animation in this controller.

Comment: @Ashiwani, something is blocking your main thread - that's why camera can not focus. Inspect your code - at least, create empty project sample and make sure that code for cardIO is working. than return to your project and comment all code that does not belong to cardIO